# Cannot get .bat file to run after installation with Qt installer

Tags: postgresql, qt, batch-file, qt-installer

I'm needing to run a `bat` file when the installer is finished that plugs in a postgres windows service so my database has an active server (I'm using a static postgres). The `bat` file runs the `pg_ctl` register command.

According to the Qt Installer Documentation `installationFinished` is what you use to issue methods that will run once the installer is complete via the controller or package install scripts. I'm not sure if i'm using it correctly because after running the installer the `bat` file doesnt run. How is this function used properly?

I have tried in the controller script:

```
Controller.prototype.installationFinished = function(){
    installer.executeDetatched("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PostgreSQL\\9.6\\pgserv.bat", new Array(), "@homeDir@")
}
```

also tried in the component install script:

```
Component.prototype.installationFinished = function(){
component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", "cmd", "/C", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PostgreSQL\\9.6\\pgserv.bat");
}
```

This `bat` file is to run post install because the command on the `bat` file requires the postgres\bin folder that is added to the `PATH` variable after install.

Thanks a lot for any help folks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Component.prototype.installationFinished = function()
{
    QDesktopServices.openUrl("file:///" + installer.value("TargetDir") + 
    "/file.bat");     
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That snippet is in the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qt-installer-framework-openreadme-example.html). I'm just mentioning because i was missing all the code to bind the file to the installationFinished method....as well as using the method incorrectly :s